# Jquery cookie-how to use cookie

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jqgrid, jquery-cookie

I need to post ID value from page with jeasyui Grid, to another demo.php,for creating pdf report. So my idea was to use cookies, like this.

```
  $(function () {

        $("#btnCookie").bind("click", function () {
        var row = $('#tt').datagrid('getSelected');
    if (row){
            $.cookie("name",row.id);
          alert($.cookie("id"));//just to check for value ,and it is OK!
            window.location.href = "demo.php";
        }});
    });
```

after submit,I get right value. 
On demo.php I use this to get cookies value:

```
         $(function () {
        if ($.cookie("id") != null ) {
           var id = $.cookie("name");

            $.removeCookie("id");
           }
    });
</script>
```

now my problem is to put cookie values in next query in php section:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM stan where id="HERE I need cookie value"
```

Comment: If you want to use a cookie in PHP, why are you asking about jQuery? https://duckduckgo.com/?q=PHP+read+cookie

Comment: Hi,tnx for answer...Because, I need just to do right that :) php cookies made a huge problem when I use them with Grid,because I try with Jq. Tnx again!

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is:

```
$_COOKIE["something"]
```

I hope you find out the rest :) 
(Make sure you use proper quotes in your string, not like you wrote it in the question; also be aware of the syntax of implanting array element refs into strings; finally, watch out for cookie value, it can be manipulated so protect your query against tricky values.)

Answer (score 0):

You're setting jQuery cookie correctly. To call it and search your database just use it in the query like so:

```
<?  
    $value = $_POST['rowValue'];

    $stmt = $con->prepare("
        SELECT * 
        FROM stan 
        WHERE id = ?
    ");

    $stmt->execute(array($value));

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   
?>
```

EDIT: Updated because of comment:

```
<script>
$.post("demo.php", {
        rowValue: row.id //The cookie value
    }
});
</script>
```

So I now understand that you want to pass the cookie value, not the cookie name to your php file. For this you don't need to set a cookie, you can just send the value to the php file. In my example I've used the jQuery ajax post function. I've updated my example PHP accordingly.

Comment: Hi men,tnx. I still have a problem,this is error:Undefined index: name, still no link between cookies,but tnx :) I try with diferent cookies,but don't work.

Comment: You need to change the name of the cookie I used in my example above to the name of the cookie you are setting in your JavaScript.

Comment: Is there posibility to use method that I wrote to get cookies in function,and just to pass down to php section ?

Comment: I've updated my PHP and provided you with some revised JavaScript.

Comment: Still problem,I try this option at first,but no result,so I will do again from start,maybe a made samo litle mistake, will be in touch :)

Comment: Just to check: in my grid page,a made this function:                     function post(){
   var row = $('#tt').datagrid('getSelected');
   if (row){
    
     $.post("../../../dompdf_0-6-0_beta3/dompdf/www/demo.php", {
        rowValue: row.id
      
   
   }) 
   
  }}, and create this, to call function:  <a href="../../../dompdf_0-6-0_beta3/dompdf/www/demo.php" class="easyui-linkbutton" onClick="post()">Kompletan prikaz</a>     ,and in demo.php,past your code,is that ok ?